# Implementing a generic distributor using protobuf extensions in Netty

Tags: netty

I'd like to use Netty and Protobuf to implement a message distributor.  The distributor would be a server that knows about the base protobuf message and that it has extensions, and pass them on to other classes that register for those extensions.

Protobuf allows declaration of the extensions in separate files, so the distributor doesn't need to know about the format of the extensions.  However it seems for this to work with the Netty plumbing that I need to create the ProtobufDecoder with an ExtensionRegistry that knows about all the extensions, otherwise I will run into the problem described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf/browse_thread/thread/3d69561b7df50bce?pli=1).

Am I missing something here, or is this something I can't do without writing my own decoder?  If there is an example in Java, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an `ExtensionRegistry` when you construct a `ProtobufDecoder`, as described in [the API documentation](http://goo.gl/oBQPc).

Comment: Thanks, Trustin - I already knew that but the bit I'm confused about is that I don't want the distributor to know about all the extensions, and therefore the ExtensionRegistry I give to the ProtobufDecoder will be pretty much empty.  I *think* that's OK - I can reserialize the message and pass it on to a handler that does it's own decoding with an ExtensionRegistry that knows about the relevant extensions.  Correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have a chance to work with protobuf extensions, so I'm not sure it's correct or not.  My guess though is, it should work.  Please get back here and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents is that you don't use the extensions if they have lists of elements or anything that could potentially result is sizable messages.  You have to use one of the length-framing decoder/encoders with the protobuf messages so they are correctly size delimited.  If you want the messages to fit in, say, 64k w/ your 2 byte size header, it's inefficient to keep calling toByteArray on your message to see if it will fit within the frame.

The alternative being using an enum on the master message, and rather than the extension, use a byte array which is the protobuf serialized message that would have been in the extension.  This way you can keep postfixing data to the message as you build it, and if you run over the size limit, you can gracefully split it in half rather than have Netty throw an exception that it's too big for the frame.